# Failed to use Tesseract OCR in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, ocr, tesseract

I installed Tesseract library using cocoapods (`pod 'TesseractOCRiOS', '4.0.0'`) and imported it in the code without problems, 
I used the following code to read a text from an image

```
let tesseract:G8Tesseract = G8Tesseract(language:"eng+ita")

tesseract.delegate = self
tesseract.charWhitelist = "01234567890"
tesseract.image = image
tesseract.recognize()
print(tesseract.recognizedText)
```

After running it crashes on the first line, the error is:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems right. You can try to use if-let condition to check the optional statement. Also have a look, if you aren't already, in this [example](https://github.com/dinhnhat0401/tesseract-ocr-sample).

```
if let tesseract:G8Tesseract = G8Tesseract(language:"eng+ita") {
    // Continue with you code. 
}
```